# finding numbers from the database whose sum is greater than or equal to a number from a query

Tags: sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE tableName 
(
    name    VARCHAR(512),
    foreign_id  INT,
    capacity    INT
);

INSERT INTO tableName (name, foreign_id, capacity) VALUES ('a', 1 , 4);
INSERT INTO tableName (name, foreign_id, capacity) VALUES ('b', 1, 6);
INSERT INTO tableName (name, foreign_id, capacity) VALUES ('c', 2, 8);
INSERT INTO tableName (name, foreign_id, capacity) VALUES ('d', 3, 2);
INSERT INTO tableName (name, foreign_id, capacity) VALUES ('e', 3, 4);
INSERT INTO tableName (name, foreign_id, capacity) VALUES ('f', 3, 6);
```

for this table
I would like to have a query which, from the number given in capacity, will arrange possible combinations adding these values to reach a number for example greater than or equal to  5

**IDEA**

```
SELECT name, capacity, foreign_id
FROM tableName
WHERE foreign_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT foreign_id FROM tableName
)
GROUP BY foreign_id, name, capacity
HAVING SUM(capacity) >= 5;
```

**BUT**
I tried such a solution, but for example for foreign_id = 3 it only returns a capacity value of 6>=5, and I would also like to get an answer of 4+2>=5

**QUESTION:**

how to find numbers from the database from capacity column whose sum is greater than or equal to a number from a query

**WANTED SOLUTION**

*For the sake of simplicity, I consider only the results for foreign_id 3*

for capcity from query = 5

**RESULST:**

| name | foreign_id | capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d | 3 | 2 |
| e | 3 | 4 |
| f | 3 | 6 |

2+4>=5 AND 6>=5 AND 6+2>=5 AND 2+4+6>=5

for capcity from query = 9

**RESULST:**

| name | foreign_id | capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d | 3 | 2 |
| e | 3 | 4 |
| f | 3 | 6 |

6+4>=9 AND 6+4+2>=9

Comment: How do you determine where to stop?  In your example, d - f has a total capacity of 12, which is greater than 5.

Comment: Do you want every single possible combination? Or do yo uwant to just go in order until the running total is >= 15

Comment: I don't need every possible combination a reasult with array with rows that can create specific number will be enough

Comment: So something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/535ba/1 showing the first 3 rows which together add up to 18

Comment: Remove the quotes from around the numbers in your VALUES list. Numbers are not strings, and therefore don't get quotes. Learn your datatypes and proper syntax - it will make things much easier for you going forward.

Comment: @Charlieface unfortunately not. I have corrected the post I hope it is now clearer what I would like to achieve. I am interested in a query that returns rows that are able to form a number greater than the one from the query. I don't need additional column that will be adding number together

Comment: @KenWhite Yep i know that, thank you for finding the error

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want *all* rows for a particular `foreign_id` where *some* of those rows could make up the value you want?

Comment: @Charlieface exactly I would like all the rows of which for each foregin_id where some of these rows can or do form a number that is greater than or equal to the value given in the query. Of course, the values of which this number is to consist are declared in the capacity column

Comment: So why wouldn't `foreign_id` 1 and 2 qualify, if they sum up to 10 and 8 respectively? Do you just want something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/535ba/3

Comment: @Charlieface i think it will work i need some time to implement this but im getting on my sql database error "#1054 - Unknown column 'totalCapacity' in 'field list'"

Comment: Yeah need to use `AS` for column aliases https://dbfiddle.uk/q3TFrBh4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to do a windowed sum

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      SUM(capacity) OVER (PARTITION BY foreign_id) AS totalCapacity
    FROM tableName tn
 ) tn
 WHERE totalCapacity >= 5;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/q3TFrBh4)

Comment: Thank you again, if I have any further questions I will write to you

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a PRIMARY KEY in your table to have any solution for this query. A table without PRIMARY KEY is not a relational table and should never exists in any RDBMS...

You should also have a limit on the number of items in the cobination of values...

An incomplete solution to this problem is as follow (for SQL Server Transact SQL):

```
DECLARE @capcity INT = 5, 
        @COMBINE_LIMIT TINYINT = 3; --> necessary to avoid too much combinations

WITH 
T AS
(SELECT 1 AS LEVEL,
        CONCAT('#', CAST(PK AS VARCHAR(max)), '#') AS PKs,  
        CAST(name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NAMEs,
        CAST(foreign_id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS FOREIGN_IDs,
        CAST(capacity AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS CAPACITIES,
        capacity AS TOTAL_CAPACITY
 FROM   tableName
 UNION ALL
 SELECT LEVEL + 1,
        CONCAT(PKs, ', ', '#', CAST(tn.PK AS VARCHAR(max)), '#'), 
        CONCAT(NAMEs, ', ', tn.name),
        CONCAT(FOREIGN_IDs, ', ', tn.foreign_id), 
        CONCAT(CAPACITIES, '+', capacity),
        capacity + TOTAL_CAPACITY
 FROM   tableName AS tn
        JOIN T ON T.PKs NOT LIKE CONCAT('%#', CAST(tn.PK AS VARCHAR(max)), '#%')
 WHERE  LEVEL + 1 <= @COMBINE_LIMIT
)
SELECT * 
FROM   T 
WHERE  TOTAL_CAPACITY >= @capcity;
```

Because you do not provide the RDBMS you have to use for this problem, I cannot finalyze this query to avoid redundant combinations like {1, 2, 3} and {1, 3, 2}... For some RDBMS you need to deal with ARRAY and some other with XML...

Comment: this its too pro form me to implement